# The php session verification file still blocks the user from visiting the page

Tags: php, authentication, session

I started learning php now and i recently learned how to use session to make the user dont acess a page that he dont got permisson ... and for some reason the 2° time that i tested this suddenly stoped working, when the user logins still blocks!
i going to send the the login.php ,protect.php and the painel.php ( its like the home page):

protect.php:

```
`<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }

    if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
        die("<h1> You dont got permisson to see this!</h1>");
    }      
      
?>
`
```

login.php

```
`<?php
    include("conecao.php");
    if(isset($_POST['email']) || isset($_POST['senha'])){
        if(strlen($_POST['email']) == 0){
            echo "Bote a email!";
        } elseif(strlen($_POST['senha']) == 0){
            echo "Bote a senha!";
        } else {
            $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
            $senha = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['senha']);

            $sql_code = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' AND senha = '$senha'";
            $sql_query = $mysqli->query($sql_code) or die("falha! no sql");
            
            $quantidade = $sql_query-> num_rows;

            if($quantidade == 1) {

                $usuario = $sql_query->fetch_assoc();

                if(!isset($_SESSION)){
                    session_start();
                }

                $_SESSION['id'] = $usuario['id'];
                $_SESSION['nome'] = $usuario['nome'];

                header("Location: painel.php");

            } else {
                echo " Sua senha ou email estão incorretos!";
            }

        }
    }
?>
```

The rest is html if you want to see i can post!

```
<?php
    include('protect.php');
?>
```

in the painel.php i just got this

I tryed everthing i remade the code, search online but i cant solve!

Comment: Try replacing `if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }` with `session_start();`. There may be other problems, but that's one.

Answer (score 0):

In your protect.php file, if a user is not authenticated (per the session variable) you should redirect the user to login.php so that they can login.

```
    if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
      header ('location: ../login.php');
    }
```

I also recommend that you look into how to debug your php code with xdebug.
That way you can step through your code line by line and look at the value inside your session array variable so that you can understand why this behaviour is happening. Hopefully that helps with your issue.

Comment: It didn't work! its just redirecting the user back to login infinite

Comment: Try to put an debugging echo after this line 
               $sql_code = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' AND senha = '$senha'";




and before this line
            $sql_query = $mysqli->query($sql_code) or die("falha! no sql");  For instance something like echo $sql_code, and then take a look at what the SQL String looks like and run that SQL statement on the database to see if it returns records.

Comment: You can try to comment out the code where you send the query to the database and replace with troubleshooting echo statements. That way you can see what the SQL Query your php is sending to your database looks like, then you can try to see if that SQL query is actually returning any records from the database.